# mat-select long option value

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i handle long value in mat-select?

Can i add horizontal scroll?

or can i make  the long option value to be 2 line?

i have tried add virtual-scroll class what i got from [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13087), but i got error

```
<mat-select formControlName="fieldOfWork" placeholder="Pilih bidang pekerjaan"  class="virtual-scroll" required>
   <mat-option [value]="null">Pilih bidang pekerjaan</mat-option>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let fieldOfWork of fieldOfWorks" [value]="fieldOfWork?.value">
      {{fieldOfWork?.label}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

How to Handle the following ?
[image]

Comment: please check my answer, if the required case or i have to modify something to meet the requirement.

Comment: Hi , somone has any suggestion for this 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670262/how-to-display-entire-option-value-when-hovered-in-mat-autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `style.css` file

```
.mat-option-text {
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: unset;
}
```

**[Stackblitz Demo showing horizontal Scroll bar inside option](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-2krif4?file=styles.css)**

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer and it will settle the width of the dropdown panel to longest value. You can try this. I have used this in angular material.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two options for the question:

1. scroll bar in the long text

```
    ::ng-deep.mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
        overflow: auto;
        text-overflow: unset;
    }
```

2. show the long text in 2 columns.

In the .scss add:

```
    .multiline-mat-option.mat-option {
        white-space: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        height: unset;
        padding-top: 0.9em;
        padding-bottom: 0.9em;
      }
```

In the Html:

```
    <mat-option class="multiline-mat-option"...
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit too late but none of the other answers worked for me. I've found that most answers just make all spaces around the options bigger, which break jumping to them by keyboard presses. This is how I've managed to solve it:

```
/* Makes the too long select options visible instead of shortened with "..." */
.mat-select-value {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.width-mat {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: unset;
}

.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
    font-size  : inherit;
    line-height: 1em;
    height     : 5em;
    white-space: unset;
}

.mat-option-text {
    line-height: 1em;
    white-space: unset;
    text-overflow: unset;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked **Abhishek Kumar's** answer, however, I found it better to scroll on the `mat-select-content` rather than the `mat-option-text`.

Below is my version

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-dumddw?file=styles.css

```css
.mat-option-text {
    overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: unset;
}

.mat-option {
    width: fit-content;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

.mat-select-content {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

with angular, you might need to include `::ng-deep` and `!important` to override angular material themes.

Answer (score -1):

**Reduce** count of characters in your array.
For example show only 50 first chars:

```
this.courseTopics.forEach(ct => {
    if (ct.title.length > 50)
      ct.title = ct.title.substring(0, 49) + ' ...'
  });
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to just ignore the problem rather than attempt to solve it