# How to display entire option value when hovered in mat-autocomplete

Tags: css, angular, mat-autocomplete

This is demo app that uses mat-autocomplete, I picked from stackoverflow post [enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-2krif4)  , I want to display option entire value. When the value is long. I found similar question asked [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233278/mat-select-long-option-value) but this hasn't solved my problem. I can scroll and see the value, can modify css style so the scroll bar is properly visible.

Looks like remaining part of scroll bar is hidden!

I tried

```
.mat-option {

z-index:5000;
height:300px;
}
```

Nothing has worked out!

It would be better if the element was shown completely.

[image]

Code snippet
**template.html**

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" panelWidth="320px">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
        <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**typescript.ts**

```
 states: State[] = [
    {
      name: 'Arkansas',
      population: '2.978M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Arkansas.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg'
    },
    {
      name: 'California CaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCaliforniaCalifornia',
      population: '39.14M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_California.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg'
    }

  ];

 constructor() {
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(state => state ? this._filterStates(state) : this.states.slice())
      );
  }

  private _filterStates(value: string): State[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.states.filter(state => state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
```

Comment: Please don't link outside websites alone. If you are able to fix the problem or if the website ever changes / goes down your question will be useless to anyone visiting in the future. A [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps remedy this and gives everyone more info to help you with.

Comment: Hi Latif Sorry, I have updated my question. Previously link was wrong one

Comment: That isn't the issue, please re-read my comment. It doesn't matter if it is the correct site or not, I didn't even open it

Comment: I edited question gave code snippet, hope that is clear

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways to solve this

1.Adding scroll to `mat-option` as you already have that in your question

2.Giving width to `mat-select`, but this will also be issue if `mat-option` is too long.

3.This option is to wrap text - add below css to `mat-option`

```
.mat-option {
 word-break: break-all;
 white-space: normal;
 height: unset;
}
```